# SwipeRefresh not displaying in a fragment with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, drawerlayout, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to display a SwipeRefreshLayout in my Fragment. I've built a TabLayout with 3 Tabs(fragment). In the first one there is a RecyclerView. I've tried to implement the SwipeRefreshLayout in CoreActivity and it works. Any suggestions? Is it possible TabLayour overrides the SwipeRefreshLayout?

Here the code:

CoreActivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.latlo.firestore.CoreActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/viewpager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />


     </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/menulaterale"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_top"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>


 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Announces_content_fragment.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
tools:context="chilor.lolmatch.AnnouncesContentFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    tools:src="@drawable/diamond_v"
    android:layout_below="@+id/queue_type"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/queue_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    tools:text="ciao"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_reply"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Reply"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/queue_type"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="24/06/17 23:00" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sender"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ADC"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_reply"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_reply"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/time" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Looking For"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/queue_type"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_reply" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/receiver"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="Support" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/summ"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textStyle="bold" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

Recycler_view.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swiperefresh2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </ScrollView>



</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Announces_content_fragment.activity:

```
public class AnnouncesContentFragment extends Fragment implements 
SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Messages> currentItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private String summoner;
    private String rank;
    private FirebaseAuth au = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private FirebaseFirestore d;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    //public static CurrentProfile current;






    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)  
    v.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    FirebaseFirestore d = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) 
    v.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh2);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewOffset(true, 1500, 1800);



    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors
    (android.R.color.holo_blue_light,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        }
    });
    try {
        setFirebaseValueListener();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    LinearLayoutManager mm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), 
    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mm);
    return recyclerView;
}


public void setFirebaseValueListener() throws ExecutionException, 
InterruptedException, JSONException {
    final FirebaseFirestore d = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    NetworkController nc = new NetworkController();
    nc.getMessages(getContext(), new ServerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSucces(JSONObject result) {
            try {
                JSONArray array = result.getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i =0;i<array.length();i++){
                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Messages mes = new 
                    Gson().fromJson(obj.toString(),Messages.class);
                    currentItems.add(mes);
                }
                summoner = "AFKMan";
                adapter = new 
                RecyclerViewAdapter(currentItems,summoner);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    try {
        setFirebaseValueListener();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing the scrollview in your `Recycler_view.xml`

Comment: @NavneetKrishna Nothing to do. It's like something is overriding the swipelayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *RecyclerView*, you don't need to worry about scrollview. Recyclerview automatically puts *Scrollview* if your list exceeds the limit of Layout.

Try removing *Scrollview* this might help.

And also it looks like you haven't included any layout parent to  *SwipeRefreshLayout*. include  *LinearLayout* or any other layout parent to  *SwipeRefreshLayout*.

**Edit**(Solves your problem)

replace

```
return recyclerView;
```

by

```
return v;
```

Comment: Nothing to do :|

Comment: include LinearLayoutl in Recycler_View.xml parent to SwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: Do you mean inside the Swipe?

Comment: No Outside the SwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: Every xml in android needs to have one main layout such as LinearLayout or RelativeLayout or FrameLayout

Comment: It doesn't work :|. Anyway in the Fragment code i create a LinearLayout for Recycler.

Comment: You got to return view in the end of onCreateView method of fragment. Include return v; (in your case), at the end of onCreateView method

Comment: replace return recyclerView;   with   return v; in onCreateView()

Comment: Thank you, now it works. But stuck now stucks on the bottom (i think for setProgressViewOffset) and doesn't go away. I'll try to fix it, if you have suggestions you help me a lot!

Comment: I don't exactly understand whats the problem. Can you describe in a detail please. And please accept my answer by clicking on right sign, if my answer helped you

Comment: Yes, i did it! No problems anymore, i fixed the circular progress in the bottom and added in "onRefresh" an Handler to disable Swipe Circular after 1 second. Thank you, i've accepted your answer!

Comment: I am glad I could help you :)